# Adding a zero to the hslide value

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Could someone help me figure out how to get the hslide value in Flash Builder to have an extra zero if the value is below 10? The problem is that I need to get a two digit value out from the hslide, but if I put in the min/max values 0-23 I will only get one digit if the value is below 10.
Example: I want to use the hslide as a time slide. If I choose 4am I need the value to be 04, not 4.

Below is my example code, it is the hslider1.value and hslider2.value that needs to be two digits.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        { navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:*23*"+hslider1.value+hslider2.value))  ;
        }       
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button y="155" width="269" height="80" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"
          color="#FFFFFF" enabled="true" fontSize="24" horizontalCenter="0"/>
<s:HSlider id="hslider1" top="405" width="90%" height="30" dataTipPrecision="0"
           horizontalCenter="0" liveDragging="true" maximum="23" minimum="0" stepSize="1" />

<s:HSlider y="469" width="90%" height="30" id="hslider2" 
           horizontalCenter="1" liveDragging="true" maximum="55" minimum="0" stepSize="5" dataTipPrecision="0"/>


<s:Label x="88" y="291" width="194" height="22" fontSize="24"
         text="{hslider1.value}" textAlign="right"/>
<s:Label x="284" y="291" width="7" height="22" fontSize="24" text=":"/>
<s:Label x="294" y="291" width="194" height="22" fontSize="24" text="{hslider2.value}"/>
```

Any type of help would be deeply appreciated! 
Best regards from Camilla in Sweden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi just replace the button1_clickhandler function with the following one..

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var str1:String = "";
    var str2:String = "";
    if(hslider1.value < 10)
    {
        str1 = "0" + hslider1.value.toString();
    }

    if(hslider2.value < 10)
    {
        str2 = "0" + hslider2.value.toString();
    } 
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:*23*"+str1+str2))  ;
}
```

Have a Nice Day...

Comment: Hi it only worked partly, now it will show the 0 before the number, if both sliders are under 10, but if one of the sliders are above ten (12:05 or 04:15) the button will only use the value that have the extra zero (only 05 or only 04), instead of both of them.

Comment: Easy fix! I only added an else statement and now it works perfectly!

Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code in case someone wants to see it:

```
    protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var str1:String = "";
            var str2:String = "";
            if(hslider1.value < 10)
            {
                str1 = "0" + hslider1.value.toString();
            } else { str1 = hslider1.value.toString();
            } 


            if(hslider2.value < 10)
            {
                str2 = "0" + hslider2.value.toString();
            } else { str2 = hslider2.value.toString();
            } 


            navigateToURL(new URLRequest("tel:*23*" + str1 + str2))  ;
        }
```